# jenkins docker on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ecs

I am running jenkins off an ec2 image and building a docker image to push into ecr

I keep getting this error

```
Running shell script
+ aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-2
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

I have tried to create the credentials file 
ie

```
touch ~/.aws/credentials and echo >> to the file
```

I have tried with

```
--build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxxx
```

and I have also added my credentials into Jenkins

Please any help would be appreciated

Comment: are you running Jenkins as a container?

Comment: Jenkins is running on an ec2 instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by configuring aws cli by jenkins user. Just fire this command as jenkins user and mention your access key and secret key along with the AWS region.

First change to Jenkins user

```
[root@symphony ~]# su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

Then configure AWS CLI

```
[jenkins@symphony ~]$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: yyyyyyyyyyyy
Default region name [None]: us-east-2
Default output format [None]:
```

Verify the aws cli with this command

```
[jenkins@symphony ~]$ aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-2
```

NOTE: Make sure your user has access to ECR and ECS.